# convergence in probability (uniform)

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

${{X}_{1}},{{X}_{2}},...,{{X}_{n}} \text{ iid }\sim U(0,a)$

$Z=\max \{{{X}_{1}},...{{X}_{n}}\}$

I found that ${{Z}_{n}}\xrightarrow{i.p.}a$ but the question asks for me to prove ${{Z}_{n}}\xrightarrow{i.p.}\sqrt{a}$

What is the actual value ${{Z}_{n}}$ converges in probability?

Comment: Are you sure of the question statement? Where does it come from?

Comment: Yes exactly stated as that. Am I right about it converges to the value a ? Probably I will prove it converges to a instead of square root of a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that $Z_{n}\xrightarrow{i.p.}a$

$Z_{n}$ has the pdf $\displaystyle f(x)=n\cdot \frac{x^{n-1}}{a^{n}}\mathbf{1}_{0<x<a}$

So $E(Z_{n})=\frac{a\cdot n}{n+1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} a$

Thus obviously if $Z_{n}$ converged in probability to a constant , then since $|Z_{n}|\leq a$ , by uniform integrability , $Z_{n}$ would converge in $L^{1}$ to the same constant which means that $E(Z_{n})$ would have converged to the same constant. Thus as $E(Z_{n})\to a$ , you must have had $Z_{n}\to a$ in probability and nothing else.

Note that what I did above is a way to check if your guess is correct or not and gives you a candidate for the limit. To conclude convergence in probability, you still have to show that rigorously. Often a time, it is the guess or the candidate for the limit which is the most troublesome aspect and is difficult to find. After that it just becomes a problem of real analysis to prove that the guess is indeed correct.

For a formal proof, you have that $P(|Z_{n}-\frac{n}{n+1}a|>\epsilon)\leq \frac{Var(Z_{n})}{\epsilon^{2}}$ due to Chebycheff's Inequality.

Now $Var(Z_{n})=\frac{a^{2}n}{n+2}-\frac{a^{2}n^{2}}{(n+1)^{2}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} a^{2}-a^{2}=0$

Thus you have $Z_{n}-\frac{an}{n+1}$ converges in probability to $0$ . Couple it with the fact that $\frac{an}{n+1}$ converges pointwise to $a$ to conclude $Z_{n}-a$ converges in probability to $0$ and hence $Z_{n}\xrightarrow{i.p.} a$

Point to take a note of is that by the guessing game I played earlier , I immediately got the expression $\frac{an}{n+1}$ as the mean . Otherwise, it would have been more painful to just conisder the expression $P(|Z_{n}-a|>\epsilon)$ as I cannot directly apply Chebycheff's inequality as $a$ is not the mean.